# Error while storing my db value into dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a lot of trouble with storing my values from a database into a dropdown list.
The code doesn't bring any errors, but it just freezes...

**Code**

```
<div class="input-field col-md-12">

          <?php
              echo "<select name='pcID'>";
              $query = "SELECT benutzername FROM benutzer";
              $result = mysql_query($query);
              if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
              echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['benutzername'] . "
             </option>";
             }
            }
            echo "</select>";
         ?>
        </div>

      </div>
```

I found a lot of other solutions for my problem. But no solution worked for me. It just freezes up (on my loading screen). And as soon as I remove the PHP part it unfreezes...

Does anyone know how I can solve my problem?

**Edit**

yea, like I said. I get no error message in the console at all...

Comment: you have an extra `</select>`

Comment: How many rows does the query return?

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @Samir so far only 2 rows...

Comment: take a second **close** look at this line and fix the glaring error `if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){`

Comment: oh, so this is going to be an "on the fly" edit, huh?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah, I commented on that and deleted my comment for it.

Comment: Oh sorry @FunkFortyNiner I did not see that.

Comment: @RiggsFolly nothing to be sorry about ;-) I didn't see yours when I deleted it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I am going for a TYPO close

Comment: @CallMeLeonardo further clue to RiggsFolly's comment...a SQL query statement is not the same thing as the **result** of that query

Comment: @RiggsFolly I removed the if statement now. Don't know why I included it tbh... But it wasn't the error. I will have a look at your suggested PDO or mysqli statements

Comment: Why so many downvotes? Pretty hard to learn a language if everyone just goes hard on beginner errors...

Comment: Change `if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)` to `if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Changed it. I see the fault there. But it still doesn't work...

Comment: Add [echo mysql_error();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) after the `mysql_query()`

Comment: "doesn't work" means what? Could be lots of things, we can't do anything with that info. Make sure PHP error reporting is switched on and that you're checking for mysql errors as Riggs suggests, and then tell us what goes wrong.

Comment: *I get no error message in the console at all* - if you're referring to the browser console, no, you won't get PHP errors in there. PHP runs on the server not the client.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I solved it by using the PDO as @RiggsFolly suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After restructuring my code, I solved it by using the PDO statements.

This is how my solutions looks like now:

```
<div class="input-field col-md-12">

          <?php
              //query
              $sql = "SELECT benutzername FROM benutzer";
              $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
              $statement->execute();
              $users = $statement->fetchAll();

          ?>

          <select>
           <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
             <option value="<?= $user['id']; ?>"><?= 
             $user['benutzername'];  ?></option>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
         </select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to connect your db by selecting appropriate database.

   ```
   $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("databasename",$con);
   ```
2. Your option tag in drop-down list just takes the value and no name to display. I'd suggest you to make minimal changes.

   ```
   echo"<option value=".$row["columnname"].">".$row["column2"]."</option>";
   ```

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).